# If $P$ is a prime ideal in a commutative ring $R$, is the ideal $P\times P$ a prime ideal in $R \times R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $P$ is a prime ideal in a commutative ring $R$, is the ideal $P\times P$ a prime ideal in $R \times R$

Comment: How about $R= \mathbb Z$, $P = \langle 2\rangle$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Matemáticos Chibchas points out, it will not be a prime ideal (assuming $R$ has a multiplicative identity), since $$(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)\in P\times P,$$ but $1\notin P,$ so $(1,0),(0,1)\notin P\times P$.

However, $P\times R$ and $R\times P$ will be prime ideals of $R\times R$ whenever $P$ is a prime ideal of $R.$

Comment: Actually "never" instead of "in general": we always have $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)\in P$, yet both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ do not belong to $P$.

Comment: That's an excellent point. I ought to have thought of that.

Comment: But $R$ might not have an identity

Comment: @ThomasFinley, fair point. Adjusted.

Comment: Ok, and why do you write $1\notin P$ ? Because if $1\in P$ then $P=R$ ? But then if, $P=R$ what's the problem?

Comment: @ThomasFinley, because $P$ is a prime ideal of $R,$ by hypothesis, so is necessarily a proper subset of $R$ by [definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Definition).

Comment: @CameronBuie Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification! +1 from me.